# domdocument regex replace tag

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, domdocument

hello I have a php regex code like this :

```
preg_replace('~<div\s*.*?(?:\s*class\s*=\s*"(.*?)"|id\s*=\s*"(.*?)\s*)?>~i','<div  align="center" class="$1" id="$2">', "html source code");
```

now what I want to do is to replace all  tags in the source html code and then keep only the class and id from the div tag plus add align="center" to it:
examples:
`<div style="border:none;" class="classbutton"> will be replaced to <div align="center" class="classbutton">`

```
<div style="border:none;" class="classbutton" id="idstyle"> will be replaced to <div align="center" class="classbutton" id="idstyle">
```

I already tried many codes using php regex but nothing seems to be working for me. so if someone can help me or give me a domdocument code to fix this issue.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that your actual HTML? If so there is a space between `<` and `div`. Also not seeing the `domdocument` usage here..

Comment: I'm using fetching using file_get_contents from a website

Comment: and then I replace all <div> tags of the website

Comment: I'm using the php regex code as described above but it's not working ,I heard domdocument can solve my problems so I'm asking for someone to give me a domdocument replacing my php regex code

Comment: This isn't a site that just `gives code`. We help with coding issues. Have you tried the using the `domdocument` yet? `domdocument` is a better approach then regexing.

Comment: I don't know how to start with domdocument if only u can help me with start I would be thankful

Answer (score 0):

Here is some snippet that should get you going:

```
$html = '<body><div style="border:none;" class="classbutton" id="idstyle">Some text</div></body>';            // Sample HTML string

$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$divs = $xpath->query('//div[@class="classbutton"]'); // Get all DIV tags with class "classbutton"

foreach($divs as $div) {                  // Loop through all DIVs found
   $div->setAttribute('align', 'center'); // Set align="center"
   $div->removeAttribute('style');        // Remove "style" attribute
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();                    // Save HTML (use $html = $dom->saveHTML();)
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/vjiH9W)